# Подключить модуль python из другого Docker контейнера

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose

возникла необходимость подключить python модуль(функцию из файла) из другого Docker контейнера,сколько бьюсь, не могу понять как это сделать и вообще возможно ли)

Папки проекта

[image: Папки проекта]

Docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  flask:
    build: ./flask
    container_name: flask
    restart: always
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=MyFlaskApp
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - "/home/nikita/app/telegram_bot"

  telegram_bot:
    build: ./telegram_bot
    container_name: telegram_bot
    restart: always

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Docker файл из flask:

```
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app 
ADD . /app

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# run the command to start uWSGI
CMD ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
```

Docker файл из telegram_bot:

```
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app 
ADD . /app

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# run the command to start uWSGI
CMD ["python", "./main_bot.py"]
```

Задача подгрузить функцию из main_bot.py, во flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
services:

  flask:
    build: ./flask
    container_name: flask
    restart: always
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=MyFlaskApp
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - /home/nikita/app/telegram_bot:/app/telegram_bot
```

по идее после этого в контейнере фласка `main_bot.py` будет доступен по пути `/app/telegram_bot/main_bot.py`

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло)